# Format number but keep decimals without round

Tags: angularjs

I have the number `32661.295286` and when I filter it using `{{realized | number:2}}` it rounds to `32,661.30` but I need the real number without a rounded decimal, I expect `32,661.29`.

How can I avoid that Angular round the decimals?

Comment: This happens cuz your value is above the half of "295.00.", it is a currency value? if you type 32661.294286 // changing the 5 for 4 you'll get what you need.

Comment: realized will round off the number, try out some custom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create your own filter like this:

```
var filters = angular.module('myFilters', []);

filters.filter('dropDigits', function() {
    return function(floatNum) {
        return String(floatNum)
            .split('.')
            .map(function (d, i) { return i ? d.substr(0, 2) : d; })
            .join('.');
    };
});
```